# Restricting the number of child type higher parent has in the relational schema

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, relational-database, database-schema

So this is the schema of the application I am developing

```
user
    id
    ...

product
    id
    userId --> foreign key, references user(id)
    name
    general_fields...

product_type1:
    id --> foreign key, references product(id)
    product_type1_fields...

product_type2:
    id --> foreign key, references product(id)
    product_type2_fields...
```

As you can see,

- we have products which can have different types
- all the products have some common fields like `name`
- and each type has its own fields

I want a user to have multiple instances of product type 2 but only one instance of product type 1. How can this constraint be achieved in the database layer?

i.e

- user has many product type 2
- user has only one product type 1
- which means user has many products

The first thing comes to my mind is adding `unique` userId field to product type1 so no duplicate userId would be inserted to product_type1 table but we already have `userId` in `type1`'s parent(which is the product table) so it may not be the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: You are right. You'll need to propagate `userId` into `product_type1`.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for answering. Do you think it is a proper way of achieving the described goal?

Comment: In table `product_type2`, what's the difference between column `id` that references `product(id)` vs column `product_id`? Asking because `product_id` sounds a lot like it would be the `id` for `product`. Please tell the declared keys for each table.

Comment: I think you're saying the columns in `product_type1` extend the columns in `product`, for the same `id`, with `type1`-specific information(?) If you make `product_type1`'s `id` the (`UNIQUE`) key for that table as well as Foreign Key, that'll make sure at most one linked `type1` appears. No need to include `userId` in `_type1`.

Comment: BTW suggest you don't name all your columns `id` unless they mean the same thing/have the same value. Put `userId` as the name in table `user`. As a rule of thumb, don't name any column `id`, because nobody other than you will be sure what you're talking about. And when I say "other than you", I include also your later self in 6 months' time coming back to modify the schema.

Comment: @AntC product_id shouldn't be there. that was a typo. thanks for informing.

I still don't get your answer `if you make product_type1's id the (UNIQUE)`. A user can still create multiple product_type_1 `product`s and all those products will have different ids so they will be unique in product_type_1 table too(which means user could have multiple instances of product_type_1)